# I want to get UID of users to store specific rating in their details but I can not access the specific users

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store rating of users in their details for the specific users I can not reach the stored users.

```
 ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Users");
 ref.equalTo("Youtubers").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
for(DataSnapshot child:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
  if(child.getKey().equals("Youtubers")){
        youtuber_id=child.getValue().toString();

     dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next().getValue().toString();

  }
} } }
```

My database:

[image]

Comment: show your database structure

Answer (score 0):

To loop over all the child nodes of `/Users/Youtubers`, you'd do:

```
ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Users/Youtubers");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()){
      System.out.println(child.getKey());
    }
  }
}
```